# return an object value from ember helper and passing through hbs template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-components

can ember return an object value from helper, and if that can how to passing to hbs template for component. Exactly I just wanna do this.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function someHelper(params/*, hash*/) {
  switch(params) {
    case 'a':
     return { a:21,b:22 }
     break;
    case 'b':
     return { a:21,b:20 }
     break;
    default:
     return { a:2,b:211 } 
  }
}):
```

And this is a hbs template

```
<p>{{some-helper object.foo}} </p>
```

how to get the value from ember helper that return object to my hbs template??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically setting select key in Ember within select field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254210/dynamically-setting-select-key-in-ember-within-select-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get` helper provided by Ember; see the [api reference](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get). I modified your helper and used `get` helper in the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/067cdd7b2a1b7615b99f6ade50dfca46?openFiles=helpers.some-helper.js%2C) to illustrate you the usage. By the way, `params` passed to helper is an array so I got the first item (0 index) from the array for the `switch` case you have provided. See `application.hbs` to see `get` helper in action. My best regards.